# How to judge decimal and date(ex 12.4.5)

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to judge words in file, if it is a word, a sentence, integer, decimal or date(ex12.2.3).  I could code for a word, sentence and integer, but I can't separate between decimal and date. Only the date is printed out and the rest are filed with each file(word, sentence integer).  How can I discreminate decimal and date?

```
def paaohjelma():
    luku=open("kokonaisluku.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") 
    while True:
        word=tiedosto.readline().rstrip()
        if word=="":
            break
        elif word.isalpha():
            sana.write(word.upper()+'\n')
        elif '.' in word and ' ' in word:
            sentence.write(word.capitalize() +'\n')
        elif word.isdigit():
            luku.write(word+'\n')
            for i in word.isdigit ():
                if type(float(i)):
                    desi.write(word+'\n')
                else:
                    print("Tunnistamaton rivi '",word,"'.",sep="")  
                    
    luku.close()
    desi.close()
    sana.close()
    sentence.close()
    return
    

tiedosto=open("riveja.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
paaohjelma()
tiedosto.close()
```

Comment: Regular expressions in Python provide a powerful mechanism. But without an example of the input data and some expected output examples, it is difficult to give you concrete suggestions.

Comment: Input data is ex "word", "1234","I live here","12,5" and "12.5.4". Word is to word file(sana.txt), "1234" is to integer file(luku.txt), "I live here" is to sentence file(virke.txt),"12,5! is to decimal file(desi.txt) and "12.5.4" should print out ("Tunnistamaton rivi '",word,"'.",sep="").  "12.5.4" is move to decimal file, but I want to print it.